# Homotopy between $^*$-homomorphisms

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra.
Denote by $SA$ the suspension of $A$,  $SA:=C_0((0,1),A)$.

If we define $F: SA \to SA$ by $(F(f))(t)=f(1-t)$ then $F$ induces group homomorphisms $$K_0(F):K_0(SA)\to K_0(SA) \ \ \ \text{ and }K_1(F):K_1(SA)\to K_1(SA).$$

> Show that $K_0(F)=-id_{K_0(SA)}$ and similarly $K_1(F)=-id_{K_1(SA)}$

I've tried to figure out which $^*$-homomorphisms from $SA$ to itself induce the homomorphism $-id$ on the $K_i$-groups. 
Then just finding a homotopy between $F$ and these homomorphisms will be suffices, but I didn't succeed to find them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about $H : [0,1] \times SA \to SA; \ H(t,f)(s) := -(1-t)f(s) + t f(1-s)$.

Comment: OK, I also thought so. But it shows that $F$ I defined above is homotopy equivalent to $G: SA \to SA$ defined by $G(f)= -f$ , i.e. $G=-id_{SA}$, and then it seems like $G$ induces the $-id$ group homomorphism on the $K$-groups. But I'm not sure that $G$ itself is a $^*$-homomorphism of $C^*$-algebras...What am I missing?

Comment: Good comment. I think my approach is to easy for this problem (then one could also consider $F = id_{SA}$ and we would have proved that $-id_{K_0(SA)} = id_{K_0(SA)}$).